# Upgrading titanium/appcelerator project

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

i had a titanium project build on sdk version 3.X.

Now the sdk is 5.X... is there any document that outlines what needs to be done to upgrade from 3.X to 5.X (or from 3.4 to 4.x to 5.x?)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any guidelines for direct upgrade from 3.X to 5.X. I would just go through the release notes: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_Release_Notes

There seem many, but only a few are major updates. It's not too bad.

Comment: I agree with Shawn. Also, when running in 5.x you will see in the console the warnings of deprecated APIs. A quick search and replace should do it rather quickly.